# laravel using validation request with except method

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am using request validation as

```
php artisan make:request ClientRequest
```

As you can see, on client edit form if password field is not empty I am able to use **$request->validated()** method on database update,

However if password field empty(user dont want to change password),

I am not able to use **$request->except('password')->validated()** method.

I use **$request->except()** method due to this situation.

Does this pose a security problem?

```html
public function update(ClientRequest $request, Client $client)
{

    $validated = $request->validated();

    if($request->filled('password') )
    {
        Client::whereId($client->id)->update($validated);
    }else{
        Client::whereId($client->id)->update($request->except('password'));
    }

    return redirect('/clients')->with('success', 'success');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Client::whereId($client->id)->update($request->except('password'));
```

That line is does pose a big security problem especially if you are relying on validation to set fields rather than the `fillable` attribute. `$request->except('password')` will return all the other fields that the user submitted so if the user had added something like `is_admin => true` in the request, you'll end up setting it on the db if it exists.

You can use `\Illuminate\Support\Arr::except()` on the validated data to make sure that you are only getting the data you expect. That would change the that particular line to

```
Client::whereId($client->id)->update(\Illuminate\Support\Arr::except($request->validated(), 'password'));
```

**PS:** You already have the client through route model binding so you don't need to query it you can update that client directly i.e

```
$client->update(\Illuminate\Support\Arr::except($request->validated(), 'password'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are validating all fields sent to `update()` in both scenarios.

You would have had an issue if you sent the *password* field in both cases, but only validated it in one of them. That's not the case.

So looks fine to me from that perspective.